# Unable to read and write DELTA files via SPYLON-KERNEL in JupyterLab: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, scala, jupyter-notebook, classcastexception, delta-lake

Unable to read delta files via spylon kernel in JupyterLab.
Upon trying to read the delta files via spylon kernel in JupyterLab I am facing the java.lang.ClassCastException error as below,
I tested other versions as well which all lead to the same error.

Steps to recreate:

spark version : 3.1.2
scala version : 2.12.15
spylon-kernel : 0.4.1

```
%%init_spark
launcher.master = "local[*]"
launcher.packages = ["io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.1"]
```

[spylon-kernel delta read error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEIJ6.png)

```
val deadlines =spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/file/")

Intitializing Scala interpreter ...
Spark Web UI available at http://jupyter-xxxx:4040
SparkContext available as 'sc' (version = 3.1.2, master = local[*], app id = local-1672036786616)
SparkSession available as 'spark'
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml

*Error:*
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (jupyter-XXXXXX executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction (org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader @5c089b2f; org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader @89842c3)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2261)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:390)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2729)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.first(Dataset.scala:2736)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.$anonfun$computedState$1(Snapshot.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withJobDescription(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:32)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:27)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.withStatusCode(Snapshot.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.computedState$lzycompute(Snapshot.scala:137)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.computedState(Snapshot.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.metadata(Snapshot.scala:179)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.toString(Snapshot.scala:290)
  at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
  at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.$anonfun$new$1(Snapshot.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.$anonfun$logInfo$1(Snapshot.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(Logging.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(Logging.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.logInfo(Snapshot.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.<init>(Snapshot.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.SnapshotManagement.createSnapshot(SnapshotManagement.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.SnapshotManagement.createSnapshot$(SnapshotManagement.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.createSnapshot(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.SnapshotManagement.getSnapshotAtInit(SnapshotManagement.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.SnapshotManagement.getSnapshotAtInit$(SnapshotManagement.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.getSnapshotAtInit(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.SnapshotManagement.$init$(SnapshotManagement.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.<init>(DeltaLog.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.$anonfun$apply$3(DeltaLog.scala:467)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.$anonfun$apply$2(DeltaLog.scala:467)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:77)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation$(DatabricksLogging.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordOperation(DeltaLog.scala:367)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLog.scala:367)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.$anonfun$apply$1(DeltaLog.scala:466)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:464)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:401)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.toBaseRelation(DeltaTableV2.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:177)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:305)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  ... 37 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction (org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader @5c089b2f; org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader @89842c3)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  ... 1 more
```

I was expecting the delta file to be read but didn't incur a package error rather a java.lang.ClassCastException

And upon trying to write back I am getting a FileFormatWriter error:

```
import io.delta._
val test_write = spark.range(0,100,15)
test_write.write.format("delta").save("test-delta")

error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:107)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1(WriteIntoDelta.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:154)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.AddFile
  at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_update(ScalaRunTime.scala:75)
  at scala.Array$.slowcopy(Array.scala:84)
  at scala.Array$.copy(Array.scala:110)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.copyToArray(ResizableArray.scala:80)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.copyToArray$(ResizableArray.scala:78)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.copyToArray(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.copyToArray(TraversableOnce.scala:283)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.copyToArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:282)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.copyToArray(Traversable.scala:108)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:291)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toArray(Traversable.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DelayedCommitProtocol.commitJob(DelayedCommitProtocol.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:220)
  ... 88 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message gives you a hint:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction
(org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader @5c089b2f; org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.SingleAction is in unnamed module of loader scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader @89842c3)
```

You have the same class (same name and package) loaded twice: once by Spark and once by Scala Reflection.

**You need to figure out why the class (likely the JAR) of Delta is loaded twice.**

I'm not familiar with Jupiter, this might be related to the `launcher.packages` you've given. Maybe it's not necessary or it has to be something else. (Only a guess).

Comment: The %%init_spark cell initiates spark session in spylon kernel and the launcher.packages here is a configuration equivalent to spark.jars.packages
So excluding the launcher.packages would result in the package unavailable error as

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: delta. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I am unsure as to why the packages are loaded twice and unable to trace them back as well.

Comment: I also tried adding these configurations ->

launcher.conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
launcher.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

Still has the same error.